# AssertEquals fails, because of multilines

Tags: java, junit, stringbuilder, multiline

I have generated two same Strings with StringBuilder

```
for(Integer value : ans.keySet())
 answer.append(String.format("%d=%d\n", value, ans.get(value)));
```

But when I write

```
assertEquals(answer, answer1);
```

Test is failed and there are no diffrences. I work in Windows.

Comment: show us full implementation along with answer1 creation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - when it works in *Windows* where does it fail then?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski it is the same, as answer

Comment: @AverinMaxim Give us the code that we can run and see. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak https://github.com/misteraverin/yandex-internship, just clone repository and run Tester.java

Comment: @AverinMaxim Just paste Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `%n` instead of `\n`.

In `String.format`, this amount to the default system line ending, which on Windows is `\r\n`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

> 'n'   line separator  The result is the platform-specific line
>   separator

Answer (score -1):

You can user Hamcrest Matchers like [ignorewhitespaces](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/text/IsEqualIgnoringWhiteSpace.html#equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace%28java.lang.String%29)

```
assertThat(answer, equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace(answer2));
```

Comment: No, wrong. Whitespace is a whitespace, line separator is line separator.

Comment: @Mejmo Even if it does not seem to match, it actually works, because in Java regex white spaces seems to include new line and carriage return. Internally `equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace` uses `replaceAll("\\s+", " ")`. But using this way would also ignore any white space changes in the value string...